# Why does IntelliJ does not auto import react router hooks?

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, react-router, importerror, react-router-dom

From v5.1 the react router supports hook. I have `"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"` in my package.json but when typing `useRouterMatch` in my component, IntelliJ does not suggest to auto import `import {useRouteMatch} from "react-router-dom";`

When adding the import manually everything works, but that's pretty inconvenient.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured out that IntelliJ seems to index packages based on `package.json`. The actual hooks are implemented in `react-router`.

Since `react-router` is a dependency of `react-router-dom` and added to `node_modules` it seems not to be indexed by IntelliJ. The solution is to also add `react-router` to `package.json`:

```
"react-router": "^5.1.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding `react-router` worked for me. This solution seems less than ideal.